# PHP - Convert Special Characters to HTML Entities

Tags: php, email, encoding

I have a problem with sending emails.  If it contains special characters, it won't send. I want to convert the special characters to HTML entities like this:

```
" ==> &quot;
& ==> &amp;
€ ==> &euro;
< ==> &lt;
....
```

How can I do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`htmlentities()` is what you're looking for:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [`htmlentities()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 1):

[`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) does this.

Use it like this:

```
$text = htmlentities($text);
```

But this should not be necessary if you provide proper charset information. Try setting the charset of your mail.

Comment: The second-to-last statement isn't entirely true.  What about `<` and `>`?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

(1) Use the htmlentities() located at http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Basic usages:

```
$clean = htmlentities($dirty, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

The "ENT_QUOTES" will result in both single and double quotes being converted (easy to change)

The "UTF-8" forces a UTF-8 char-set (important, read below)

(2) Force a charset on BOTH the form page and the submit-to page.

Just below your opening php brackets insert the following:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

It is important that you force a charset on both pages (realistically, on every page of your website.)

That should resolve the issues. If not, you have issues elsewhere within your purification system.