# htmlentities dont work for me

Tags: php, encoding

I am trying to encode html characters in some text to send in an email.
I used this: htmlentities, but it didn't work for me.

I tried this example :

```
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";
// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);
// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

from: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlentities.php

Can you please, explain why it didn't work?

Comment: And what "doesn't work", what would you like to see?

Comment: You'll have to be way more specific in how htmlentities does not work. The above outputs are correct What output do you expect to get? What do you actually get?

Comment: You should describe the whole context in which this example is not working as expected: **What did you try, what did you expect, and what did happen?**

Answer (score 0):

htmlentities is used to escape characters meaningful in HTML, like < and >. It is useful if you want to display those characters on a webpage without disrupting the HTML. Its is not meant to display HTML in an email.

Comment: Please can you see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808373/php-convert-special-characters-to-html-entities , i wont find solution. but i dont now how i can test htmlentities. In browser or log in fil ?

Comment: the example you tried is just the behaviour you're looking for