# Special character to HTML characters

Tags: php, html

I am inserting the user input into a DB using PHP.

Can I replace the special characters in the input into HTML characters like: `& = &amp ; ' =, &apos ;`

I only want the special characters to been replaced.

The user has to chose to format the design of his profile so the text-editor puts millions of div's with id´s inside my table this way they would get converted into a "safe" strings

```
< div id='test'> my name is john< /div>
```

Should output:

```
&lt ; div id &equals ;&apos ;test &apos ; &gt ;my name is john &lt ;&sol ;div   &gt ;
```

https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: i think preg_replace wont work for me becouse i wannt every special Character to html not one or 2 specific to 1 or 2 other

Comment: Without a more accurate example of what you are actually trying to replace we will just be guessing

Comment: There is a standard way to do this on every platform. Under no circumstances use regular expressions. You need to tell us what platform you are using, perhaps show some code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

Comment: There are many answers on this question: "PHP - Convert Special Characters to HTML Entities" https://stackoverflow.com/q/4808373/2430549  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This function could help you htmlentities.
more info about this function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: ty you. i will try it out